# convert a string to oracle sql timestamp Mon Aug 19 2019 08:21:48 GMT-0700 (PDT)

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

Greeting Community.

I saw similar examples in Java but how do we do it it SQL in particular Oracle.
For now I just do this which it works because we are in PDT timezone.

-Thx for the help!

```
with xx as ( 
select replace('Mon Aug 19 2019 08:21:48 GMT-0700 (PDT)',' GMT-0700 (PDT)','') as dt from dual

)

select to_date(dt,'DY MON DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from xx
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the column or variable you need to put this timestamp value into? Is it TIMESTAMP or TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE? Thanks.

Comment: It is date. We got an excel file with string like the example. We can put in date or timestamp but once it is in oracle it is relatively easy.

Comment: Aside from your question - where is this string coming **from**? Whoever or whatever produces this string is doing it the wrong way. Either they show GMT-0700 **or** they show PDT; they shouldn't show both. At best they agree, and there is redundant info; at worst, they contradict each other, in which case it's all garbage.

Comment: Bob's question is more meaningful than you think. The input is a timestamp **with time zone**. The important bit here is not "timestamp" vs. "date" data type; rather, it is the time zone bit. If you receive that string, and you save it as DATE, then you are losing information. Are ALL your dates, ALWAYS (including IN THE FUTURE!) in the PDT time zone, in which case you don't care and you only store the date and time components, without the time zone? Or do you need to store the FULL information from the input in your Oracle table?

Answer (score 2):

The input is a timestamp with time zone. It has redundant information about the time zone; some of that must be stripped away. For example, if you choose to trust PDT and ignore the GMT offset, you could do something like this:

```
with xx as ( 
select regexp_replace('Mon Aug 19 2019 08:21:48 GMT-0700 (PDT)','GMT-\d{4} \(|\)') 
       as str_ts_with_tz 
from   dual
)
select to_timestamp_tz(str_ts_with_tz,'Dy Mon DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZD') 
       as oracle_ts_with_tz 
from   xx
;



ORACLE_TS_WITH_TZ                      
---------------------------------------
2019-08-19 08:21:48 America/Los_Angeles
```

Note that the resulting data type is timestamp **with time zone**. You can further cast this as timestamp or as date (simply discarding the time zone information) if needed; this is a simple operation, internal to Oracle. But that **will** lose information; think twice before you do that.

Note also that the timestamp is presented in a different format in my output, compared to your input. This is because my `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT` is `'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss tzr'`.

If you are wondering why you must make a choice (which, then, means "why you need to delete part of the input string first") regarding the time zone information: PDT is simply not the same as GMT-0700. It may be that in summer, but not in winter. Oracle won't accept such self-contradicting nonsense as input to its functions. Either it's GMT-0700 or it's PDT, it can't be both. And, you can't just use REPLACE (not easily, anyway), because what must be replaced may have variable characters in it.